# Kafka consumer, very long rebalances

Tags: apache-kafka

We are running a 3 broker Kafka 0.10.0.1 cluster. We have a java app which spawns many consumer threads consuming from different topics. For every topic we have specified different consumer-group.

A lot of times I see that whenever this application is restarted one or more CGs take more than 5 minutes to receive partition assignment. Till that time consumers for that topic don't consume anything. If I go to Kafka broker and run consumer-groups.sh and describe that particular CG I see that it is rebalancing. 
In server.log I see such lines

Preparing to stabilize group otp-sms-consumer
Stabilized group otp-sms-consumer

And between these two logs there is usually a gap of about 5 minutes or more.
On consumer side when I turn trace level logs, there is literally no activity during this pause time. After a couple of minutes a lot of activity starts.
There is time critical data stored in that topic like otp-sms and we cannot tolerate such long delays. What can be the reason for such long rebalances.

Here's our consumer config

```
auto.commit.interval.ms = 3000
auto.offset.reset = latest
bootstrap.servers = [x.x.x.x:9092, x.x.x.x:9092, x.x.x.x:9092]
check.crcs = true
client.id =
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
enable.auto.commit = true
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = otp-notifications-consumer
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = null
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 50
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 305000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = SSL
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 300000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = /x/x/client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Please help.

Comment: how much time is spent to process one message in your application?

Comment: For stuck CG topics,10ms to 50ms per message

Comment: Can you try assign instead of subscribe?

Answer (score 2):

Rebalance timeout is equal to `max.poll.interval.ms` (5 minutes in your case) When rebalance starts in a group, Kafka revokes all the consumers in that group. Then waits for all alive consumers (consumers which send heartbeat) to poll() and send JoinGroupRequest.

This waiting process will end up with rebalance timeout or all the alive consumers poll() and Kafka assign partitions to these consumers.

So in your case you probably have a long running process in one of your consumers, and Kafka waits this process to complete to assign partitions.

For more information you can check these:

> Consumer groups are an essential mechanism of Kafka. They allow
>   consumers to share load and elastically scale by dynamically assigning
>   the partitions of topics to consumers. In our current model of
>   consumer groups, whenever a rebalance happens every consumer from that
>   group experiences downtime - their poll() calls block until every
>   other consumer in the group calls poll(). That is due to the fact that
>   every consumer needs to call JoinGroup in a rebalance scenario in
>   order to confirm it is still in the group.
>
> Today, if the client has configured `max.poll.interval.ms` to a large
>   value, the group coordinator broker will take in an unlimited number
>   of join group requests and the rebalance could therefore continue for
>   an unbounded amount of time.
>   (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-389%3A+Introduce+a+configurable+consumer+group+size+limit)

-

> Since we give the client as much as max.poll.interval.ms to handle a
>   batch of records, this is also the maximum time before a consumer can
>   be expected to rejoin the group in the worst case. We therefore
>   propose to set the rebalance timeout in the Java client to the same
>   value configured with max.poll.interval.ms. When a rebalance begins,
>   the background thread will continue sending heartbeats. The consumer
>   will not rejoin the group until processing completes and the user
>   calls poll(). From the coordinator's perspective, the consumer will
>   not be removed from the group until either 1) their session timeout
>   expires without receiving a heartbeat, or 2) the rebalance timeout
>   expires.
>
> (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your cluster version is at least 0.10.1.0 as I see `max.poll.interval.ms` in your consumer configuration which was introduced in this [version](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/documentation.html#upgrade_1010_notable).

Kafka 0.10.1.0 integrates [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread) which introduces a rebalance timeout set to `max.poll.interval.ms` and its default value is 5 minutes.

I guess if you don't want to wait timeout expiration during a rebalance, your consumers need to cleanly leave consumer group by calling `close()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your consumer configuration seems reasonable.  I would advise trying three things:

- Try to spawn a single consumer thread, and assign it only one of the topics you're trying to consume from.  That single thread should get all partitions for that topic assigned, and it should immediately start receiving all the data.  You can try to print out the partition and message offset, as well as content, to validate that it's getting all the data.
- Once you validate that's working, spawn a single consumer thread, and assign it *all* the topics you're trying to consume from.  Do the same validation printing out the messages.
- Finally, if that is working fine, start adding consumer threads one by one, and see if you start getting pauses when consuming.

That should allow you to pinpoint where the problem is.  If you're able to consume everything with a single thread, but not with multiple threads, then your threading mechanism/pooling might have issues.

Comment: I cannot do that. If I reduce number of threads output will go down drastically. My threading mechanism is very simple. I am just creating a java fixed thread pool and adding 5 or 10 threads in it. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I am facing too many problems these days. Now one of our consumer groups is rebalancing every now and then. And rebalance takes very low, more than 5-10 minutes. Even after re-balancing I see that only half of the consumers are active/receive assignment. Its all going haywire

Answer (score 0):

Check the `__consumer_offsets` partitions size on disk. We faced similar issue that was due to compaction errors. This leads to very long rebalances.
See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5413 for more details (solved since kafka 0.10.2.2 / 0.11)
Another option is that that your broker configuration is incorrect, and compaction is turned off, and `log.cleaner.enable` if false. `__consumer_offsets` is a compacted topic, so if log.cleaner is disabled, it will not be compacted and lead to the same symptom.

Comment: Ok, I will check this. However, I can see that log.cleaner.enable property is true by default. And we haven't tinkered around with that in our configuration.

Comment: Probably the bug is what hits you... but nothing bad in being thorough

Comment: I was referring to the bug reported in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5413 (the configuration of log cleaner is just another thing on the check list). Look at the log files for your log cleaner, or check the size on disk of __consumer_offsets topic. I'm pretty sure that's the issue since it matches the version you are using