# Kubernetes : How to detect total replicas from within a Java micro service

Tags: java, kubernetes, microservices

**What I'm trying to solve :** Have a Java microservice be aware of total number of Replicas. This replica count is dynamic in nature

**Problem:** Kubernetes downward API has limited metadata that doesnt include this information. Is there a way to qausi-query a kubectl-like command natively from a container?

**Why am I trying to do this:** In relation to Kafka, new replica will cause a rebalance. Looking to mitigate rebalancing when new containers come online/offline with additional business logic.

**Goal:** Create an arbiter java-service that detects replica count for deployment *xyz* and orchestrates corresponding pods to yield on Kafka connection until criteria is met

*also if this is crazy, I wont take offense. In that case I'm asking for a friend*

Comment: have you went through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679271/kafka-streams-on-kubernetes-long-rebalancing-after-redeployment)? especially static memberships could suite your use case.

Comment: You could use [KEDA](https://keda.sh/) to partially solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Kubernetes downward API has limited metadata that doesnt include this information. Is there a way to qausi-query a kubectl-like command natively from a container?

You need to query the Kubernetes API server for info about the number of replicas for a specific Deployment. You can do this with [kubernetes-client java](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java).

> Why am I trying to do this: In relation to Kafka, new replica will cause a rebalance. Looking to mitigate rebalancing when new containers come online/offline with additional business logic.

Sounds like you want *consistent* number of Pods all the time, e.g. **avoiding Rolling Deployment**? In your Deployment, you can set `strategy:` to `type: Recreate` - then the current Pod will be removed first, and then the new will be created - so at most 1 is running at the same time (or the same number as replicas).

### StatefulSet

When you want **at most X number of replicas** you should consider using `StatefulSet` as its behavior differ from `Deployment` when e.g. a Node becomes unreachable. `Deployment` has the behavior, **at least X number of replicas**.

Comment: The strategy type 'Recreate' appears to only take action when a version is changed. When services fall-over/die the pods of the deployment will get recreated one-by-one causing Kafka to rebalance. I was expecting all the pods to come offline at the same time which would have been an ideal solution from a Kafka perspective

Comment: If you use `StatefulSet` instead of `Deployment` you get that behavior even when the pod/node fail or die.

Comment: There are two valid update strategies, RollingUpdate and OnDelete. from https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/

Comment: StatefulSet has a different behavior when a node becomes unreachable, e.g. if replicas: 2, then it means **at most 2 replicas** but for Deployment it means **at least 2 replicas**. See e.g. https://medium.com/tailwinds-navigator/kubernetes-tip-how-statefulsets-behave-differently-than-deployments-when-node-fails-d29e36bca7d5